# Error: This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments) [Instantiatable]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-context

Everything went fine while compiling in debug mode. But while compiling in Release configuration, following error occurs :

> Error: This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments) (tb.lo.MyTabFactory) [Instantiatable]

This is the code:

```
public class MyTabFactory implements TabContentFactory {
    private final Context mContext;

    public MyTabFactory(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        View v = new View(mContext);
        v.setMinimumWidth(0);
        v.setMinimumHeight(0);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message clearly tells you what to do: `This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following constructor as the error says. It should work.

```
public MyTabFactory() {

    }
```